# How to tell when AxWindowsMediaPlayer is downloading?

Tags: vb.net

I am using AxWindowsMediaPlayer on VB.NET to preview MP3 files from the web so that the user can choose to download it if he likes it. It works. I just put a link in the URL property and after a while it begins playing.

... after a while, of course. Because it has to download the file first. Perhaps I realized that because of my slow connection XD.

But that made me think: how can I tell if the player is currently downloading a file? So that I can put a label saying "Please wait, preparing file..." or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the [Buffering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562390.aspx) Event and the [BufferingProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564813.aspx) Property. According to the MSDN Link:

> Use this event to determine when buffering or downloading starts or stops. You can use the same event block for both cases and test IWMPNetwork.bufferingProgress and IWMPNetwork.downloadProgress to determine whether Windows Media Player is currently buffering or downloading content.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can now tell if the player is buffering. But I don't quite understand how to get that progress property..

Comment: @Omega The MSDN example is using a timer that is started when the buffering starts and stopped according to the PlayState. The Tick Event is then calling the BufferingProgress property

Comment: Wait... "newState" is not a member of AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_BufferingEvent

Comment: @Omega I can not find a listing for the EventArgs for the BufferingEvent. Try putting a breakpoint on it and explore what is available.

Comment: @omega You may want to also try looking at this [`openState Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562453.aspx)